# How to get all the IDs of selected nodes to root node in jsTree?

Tags: javascript, jstree

How to get IDs of selected nodes to root node in jsTree?

Assume F and D are selected nodes , I want to get all the ids include A B C D F

- A
- - B
- - - C
- - - - D
- - - - E
- - - F

Following code will return only immediate selected ids D and F

```
    var  getMenuIds = function(){
        var menuIds = $("#menu-tree").jstree("get_checked");
        window.alert(menuIds.join(","));
        $('#menuIds').val(menuIds.join(","));
     }
```

Is there any way to get all parent nodes ID i.e. Selected node to root node ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Call [get_path](https://www.jstree.com/api/#/?f=get_path) to get the path to each selected node.

Something like:

```
var tree = $("#menu-tree");
var menuIds = tree.jstree("get_checked");
var paths = menuIds.map(function (id) { return tree.jstree("get_path", id); });

// remove duplicates
var selected = [];
var uniq = {};
paths.forEach(function (path) {
  path.forEach(function (id) {
    if (!uniq[id]) {
      uniq[id] = true;
      selected.push(id);
    }
  });
});

window.alert(selected.join(","));
```